# How to print values from array field from Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following courses array in Firestore:

[image]

How can I print all the items in `Courses` array?

I have the following code which currently just fetches the data from Firestore:

```
printAllValuesFromArray() {
    var courses = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('CurrentCourses')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      return value['courses'];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly fetching the document of the user, all you need is to just print the value like the following:

```
Future<void> printAllValuesFromArray() {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('CurrentCourses')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .get()
      .then((document) {
    final courses = document['Courses'];
    for (var course in courses) {
      print(course);
    }
  });
}
```

**Note:** You were using incorrect key to access the courses from the document which was `courses` while the correct one is `Courses` with capital `C`,

Answer (score 1):

```
value['courses'].forEach((val) {
print(val);
});
```

// Can you try this

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
printallvaluesfromarray() {

    var courses = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('CurrentCourses')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
        print(value.toString())
      return value['courses'];
    });
  }
```